# hyphen used to mean "to"

Tags: punctuation

In nonfiction, can the hyphen be used for dual purposes (i.e., between figures and in compound modifiers) within the same phrase? Unfortunately, I cannot recast these commonly uttered phrases.
This would supersede unsightly suspended hyphenation. Good to all below - yes or no?

a group of 45-55-year-old men

a $90-$95-million-a-year industry

20-25-, 30-35-, and 40-45-year-old men
75-95-cent-per-week raises

a 5½-10-minute explanation

10-20-gallon containers

within a 50-100-mile radius

a 20-30-mile commute

Thank you.

Comment: The combination of both hyphens looks quite odd. It would be OK to say "a 20–30 mile commute" (note that stylistically an en-dash looks better here than a hyphen). Or if there is a single number rather than a range, you can say "a 20-mile radius", although the hyphen is optional here and is often omitted. But the combination of the two hyphens is just wrong and looks ugly.

Comment: I suppose a combination (40–45-year-old men) is one possible style choice.